# Button remain disabled even when input field with type="emali" not empty

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form with input type="email". Now I need the submit button to be disabled until the input field is empty, however if the user enters anything the button should be enabled.
Using ng-disabled on the button, but the problem is that the button remains disabled even after I enter something into the field and remains disabled until I enter a valid email id.
My guess that the html5 validation occurs before the angular js functionality can evoke or something like that.

```
<input type="email" class="span3"   name="emailValue" ng-model="emailValue">
<button class="btn " type="button" ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="!emailValue">
```

Any kind of help is deeply appreciated. I'm new to front end so i'm lost as in where to look for.

Comment: Your first line is missing a closing quote on the `ng-model` value. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<button class="btn " type="button" ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="emailValue==''">
```

that should work

................................................

Comment: just tested your example. Because your input is of 'email' type it has to run through the validator before being applied to the data model. So while user hasnt entered a valid input in form of name@domain.com, the value emailValue will be 'undefined' thus it will not be caught by !emailValue

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure it's a falsy value first. Simple

```
$scope.emailValue = '';
```

in the corresponding controller will do the trick